# Do I need to tell TypeScript when a partial is complete, and if so, what's the best way to do that?

Tags: typescript

I am making an object that initially has only part of the type's required properties, so I am using `Partial<Type>` to tell TypeScript that's OK.

Later I add the missing property (`address`). Right now I'm using `as` to tell TypeScript that the `RawAccountWithAddress` is complete - i.e. that the type is now `RawAccountWithAddress` rather than `Partial<RawAccountWithAddress>`. Using `as` feels like a hack though.

```
const rawAccountWithAddress: Partial<RawAccountWithAddress> = ...
rawAccountWithAddress.address = ... 
return rawAccountWithAddress as RawAccountWithAddress;
```

Is this the best way to tell TypeScript the `Partial<Type>` is now `Type`? Shouldn't TypeScript just know that the partial is now complete, since the missing property has been assigned?

Is there a better way of doing this?

For reference the type is:

```
interface RawAccountWithAddress extends RawAccount {
  address: PublicKey;
}
```

Comment: TypeScript doesn't keep track of which properties you did and didn't provide values for - Partial makes _all_ of them optional, and that's the interface you're still accessing the value through. A better option might be to weaken just that one property to optional, such that `{ ...mostOfIt, lastProp: value }` is provably complete, but there's not enough information about context here to tell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're expecting [assignment narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#assignments) to apply to the parent object when a property is set, but that doesn't happen, because it would involve synthesizing new object types anytime a property changes, and that would be expensive for the compiler.  Still, there is an open issue suggesting this sort of gradual initialization at [microsoft/TypeScript#35086](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35086), and a more general open issue for narrowing parent objects upon narrowing of their properties at [microsoft/TypeScript#42384](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42384).  If you're interested in seeing this happen you might want to go to those issues and give them a  and/or comment describing why your use case is compelling and why workarounds aren't sufficient.

One workaround which *may* be sufficient, depending on the use case, is to wrap the concept of "setting a property narrows the parent" in its own [assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions).  Here's one way to write it:

```
function setProp<
    T extends object,
    K extends PropertyKey,
    V extends K extends keyof T ? T[K] : any
>(obj: T, key: K, val: V): asserts obj is
    Extract<(T & Record<K, V>) extends infer O ? {
        [P in keyof O]: O[P]
    } : never, T> {
    (obj as any)[key] = val;
}
```

That basically says that after you call `setProp(obj, key, val)`, the compiler can narrow `obj` from whatever type it started with to a version of that type where its known to have a key of `key` whose value is the type of `val`.    Here's a sketch of how it works:

- This is a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function in three type parameters `T`, `K`, and `V` corresponding to the three function parameters `obj`, `key`, and `val` respectively.
- The `V` type parameter is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) so that if `obj` already has a key `key`, then `val` must be some subtype of the property value there.  This will usually prevent someone from clobbering an existing property with an invalid type.
- The output type is based on an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of the original type `T` and [the `Record<K, V>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype) meaning an object with properties of key type `K` and value type `V`.  Then we take this intersection and use [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types), [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) and [the `Extract<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) to make the output type prettier than an intersection.  If this is too confusing you could just use `T & Record<K, V>`.

Again, it depends on use case whether this form works for you.  The general idea is that we can convey that the act of calling `obj[key] = val` can be treated as a narrowing on `obj`.

Let's try it out:

```
interface Foo {
    bar: string;
    baz: number;
}

function makeFoo(): Foo {
    const foo = {};
    setProp(foo, "bar", "abc");
    foo; // { bar: string; } 
    setProp(foo, "baz", 123);
    foo; // { bar: string; baz: number }
    return foo; // okay
}
```

That works whether or not you [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) `foo` as `Partial<Foo>`.  You can see that `foo` is narrowed from `{}` to `{bar: string}` and then to `{bar: string; baz: number}`, after which it is seen as assignable to `Foo` and accepted as the return value.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#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)

Comment: I wanted to say thanks for the links to the upstream issues too - assignment narrowing felt like something that belongs in TS itself and it's useful to track the discussion upstream.